# Android Log.d Print Line Number

Tags: android

I catch the following code in a try/catch statement:

```
            catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("MyTag", "exception ->: "+e.toString());
        }
```

It prints:

```
MyTag: exception ->: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

How can I make it print the line number along with the error message because I am finding it difficult to locate this null object reference string within my code?

Comment: have u tried `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method with the Throwable at the end:

```
catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("MyTag", "exception ->:", e);
}
```

[Log Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to rewrite your `Log` statement as:

```
Log.d("MyTag", "Exception while doing ...", e);
```

(where you replace the "..." with a few words about what the `try` block was trying to do)

This will print a complete stack trace, along with your two strings, [to LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

The **vast** majority of Android developers go this route and should go this route.

If, for some reason, you *really* want to just get the line number, `e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()` [should have that information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903903/115145). However, in many cases, that will not be a line number in your Java file, but a line number in some other Java file where the exception occurred. This is why printing the stack trace is a better option, as you get more files and line numbers.